# onclick on selected elements and non selected elements jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In the following jquery code how can I include onclick event on `<p>Click D3</p>`, I included d1 and d2's onclick p. I dont know how to include `<p>Click D3</p>` click event in the same statement i.e. `$(".d1,.d2").on('click','p',function(){`

```js
$(".d1,.d2").on('click','p',function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1">
  <p>Click D1</p>
</div>
<div class="d2">
  <p>Click D2</p>
</div>
<p>Click D3</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `parent.on('click', element,  function (){})` then you can't really do anything but add a div (`.d3`) and select the `p` inside that.. if you don't have any other `p` tags, then you could change the event listener to :
`$("body").on('click', 'p' ,function (){ console.log($(this).text()); });` 
OR You could wrap all of these `p` tags inside one div too

```js
$(".d1, .d2, .d3").on('click','p',function (){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d1">
  <p>Click D1</p>
</div>
<div class="d2">
  <p>Click D2</p>
</div>
<div class="d3">
<p>Click D3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I consider this to be the answer, because all other answers are similar but you posted it first.

Answer (score 0):

add new class name for resolve it.

```js
$('.d p').on('click', function(e){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d d1">
<p>Click D1</p>
</div>
<div class="d d2">
<p>Click D2</p>
</div>
<div class="d">
<p>Click D3</p>
</div>
```